# Codeacademy -listing everybody- returning undefined

Tags: javascript

I wrote this code as part of CodeAcademy javascript course. The code creates two objects 'bob' and 'mary' and assigns them to 'contacts' array.

The 'list' function loops through the 'contacts' array and returns the firstName + lastName utilising the 'printPerson' function

Below is the result i get from running the code:

> Bob Jones
>
> undefined   **--> cant figure out why undefined?**
>
> Mary Johnson
>
> undefined
>
> 2 **--> contacts.length - shouldnt this read 1?**

```
var bob = {
firstName: "Bob",
lastName: "Jones",
phoneNumber: "(650) 777-7777",
email: "bob.jones@example.com"
};

var mary = {
firstName: "Mary",
lastName: "Johnson",
phoneNumber: "(650) 888-8888",
email: "mary.johnson@example.com"
};

var contacts = [bob, mary];

function printPerson(person) {
console.log(person.firstName + " " + person.lastName);
}
var list = function() {
var contactLength = contacts.length
for (i = 0; i < contactLength; i++) {
    console.log(printPerson(contacts[i]));
    }
}
list();
console.log(contacts.length);
```

Comment: `printPerson` returns `undefined` - which you are logging

Comment: you have two elements in the array - why would it say the length is **1**?

Comment: @ Jaromanda X answer. Just use like this printPerson(contacts[i]) inside for loop.

Comment: @ Jaromanda X : You're right my bad! I was mixing the index value of the array with the length method. Still i cant figure out why does it return 'undefined'?

Comment: because you don't return anything ... which is equivalent to `return undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop you're calling `console.log(printPerson(contacts[i]));`

JavaScript will at first ignore the `console.log()` part and start with evaluating the inner part, `printPerson(contacts[i])`.
It's a function call, so JS calls the function, which logs "Bob Jones" to the console. Then, since the function doesn't `return` anything, the function call is evaluated as `undefined`.

Next, JS returns to the ignored part, plugs in the evaluated expression and runs the command: `console.log("undefined")`

To avoid this you can either `return person.firstName + " " + person.lastName;` in the function instead of logging it, or you just call `printPerson(contacts[i]);` in your loop.

The array's length is 2 because it contains 2 elements.

Answer (score 1):

It shows undefined in console because your function `printPerson` does not return value (which kind of means it returns undefined).

You could change your function to return value instead of logging:

```
function printPerson(person) {
  return person.firstName + " " + person.lastName;
}
```

`contacts.length` logs 2 as expected - you have two objects in your array.

Comment: Thank you apieceofbart and Jaromanda X. Code is working correctly now. Much appreciated!